# Horror movie where girls are held captive by a man who is white, in good shape, and can crawl on ceilings and walls

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Girls are held captive. Man who is holding them is white, in good shape, and can crawl on ceilings and walls. Creepy guy. What is the movie name?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, what did the place the girls were held captive in look like? And were the girls tied up/shackled, or just locked inside a room or building?

Comment: Laurel, good title edit: "Don't know the name of movie" takes the cake of most unhelpful title ever. Well, I suppose "Question" would win.

Answer (score 14):

I think you mean ***[Split](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4972582/)*** (2016), the M. Night Shyamalan movie with James McAvoy.

> Though Kevin (James McAvoy) has evidenced 23 personalities to his trusted psychiatrist, Dr. Fletcher (Betty Buckley), there remains one still submerged who is set to materialize and dominate all of the others. Compelled to abduct three teenage girls led by the willful, observant Casey, Kevin reaches a war for survival among all of those contained within him -- as well as everyone around him -- as the walls between his compartments shatter.

Comment: Yes that is it. For the life of me I couldn't remember such an easy name. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user168245 - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Comment: What a coincidence... I just watched this last night.